# Would the following NFA accept all strings?

Tags: proof-writing, examples-counterexamples, automata

The question asks the following: "Let N be a nondeterministic finite automaton with s states. Suppose than N accepts all strings of length s or
less. Does it follow that N accepts all strings? (If so, give a proof. If not, give a counter-example.)"

An idea that I've been getting is that since this would be an NFA, it can just be constructed with a certain number of states and thus have the ability to have one state transition to another, and say there are 5 states, there would be 4 transitions, where the 5th state would be the accepting state. Putting it in general terms, there could be k states, and k-1 transitions between all the states where one state moves to the next. This would accept a string with length less than the number of states. Would this be a correct approach or is there another way that would work more effectively? Thanks!

Comment: It's not quite clear to me how you're planning to answer the question with your proposed approach.

Comment: If the goal is a counterexample then you should pick a specific $s$ and then try and design a specific $N$ that will recognize all strings of length $s$ or less.  Try starting with $s = 2$ and an alphabet with only one letter.  If you get a counterexample then great, if not then ask yourself why and whether this problem will occur in general.

Comment: @Jim:  I think that would be good as an answer.

Comment: I tried to revise my idea, and came up with an NFA with two states. The first state will have a transition looping on itself with a 1. It will also be an accepting state. Then if it is an empty string, it transitions to the trash state, and another transition will loop onto the trash state for an empty string read. Would this be considered a good counter example as it rejects the empty string but accepts everything else?

Comment: No. A counterexample with $2$ states would accept every string of length $0,1$, or $2$ and reject at least one longer string.

Comment: @Somebody:  Also, your example _does_ accept the empty string.  The automaton doesn't need to explicitly read the empty string in order to accept it if the start state is also an accept state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An NFA with $5$ states and an input alphabet of $m$ symbols could have as many as $5(m+1)$ transitions, if you allow $\epsilon$-transition, or $5m$ transitions, if you do not allow them. But more to the point, what you’ve written so far doesn’t really even approach the question. First you have to decide whether the answer to the first question is *yes* or *no*; then you have to justify your answer, with a proof for *yes* or an example for *no*.

HINT: The answer is *no*, but I don’t know a really small example: the smallest that I know has $11$ states and accepts every input of length at most $29$. Instead of describing it, I’ll tell you where to find it and let you try to dig it out: the NFA is the machine $N_3$ described in the proof of Lemma $2$ of [this PDF](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ccalabro/essays/fsa.pdf). You can ignore the proof itself: just try to draw $N_3$ from the description int the first paragraph of the proof and verify that it has $11$ states, accepts $1^n$ for $n<30$, and rejects $1^{30}$.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a smaller example!

Comment: @Tara: I shouldn’t be surprised, but I couldn’t come up with one in the time that I was willing to spend.

Comment: @brian-m-scott  Your answer using prime numbers is very nice, but your automaton has $\varepsilon$-transitions. I wonder what happens for DNAs without $\varepsilon$-transitions.

Comment: @brian-m-scott  Ooops. I meant NFA of course.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: I simply don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's unary construction based on Landau's function:

7 states, split into 3-loop and 4-loop. Both loops have all but 1 state accepting.
Starting states are the ones right after rejecting ones. (if you want single starting state - add starting accepting state that proceed to these, adds 1 state and 1 accepting length)

That double loop rejects once per LCM(3,4)=12 symbols. We start at position right after rejection, so there's 11 more moves before we get there.

In total 7(8) states and first rejection at $1^{11}$ ($1^{12}$)

---

Binary construction kinda based on [On NFAs Where All States are Final, Initial, or Both](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2417) paper

2 states, both starting and final
symbol A cycles states (s1 -A> s2, s2 -A> s1)
symbol B loops all but 1 state (s1 -B> s1)

shortest rejected string is of length 2n-1: BAB
total: 2 states, first rejection at $|w|=3$